# Neo4j native api data not picked by Spring Data Repos

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I've got some data that has been pumped into a neo4j instance using the native api. The same instance is used by an app backed by Spring data graph. The repositories fail to find the data. I'm assuming that this is an issue due to indexes and/or missing properties.

When the data is pumped in the following properties are set:

```
node.setProperty("__type__", "com.x.x.Class");
```

Index is set as follows:

```
Index<Node> typeIndex = indexManager.forNodes("__types__");
typeIndex.add(node, "className", "com.x.x.Class");
```

Any clues/help is appreciated.

Comment: I also think that the SDN specific properties/indexes should be documented.

Comment: they are documented in the manual: http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-graph/snapshot-site/reference/html/#reference:programming-model:typerepresentationstrategy

Answer (score 0):

imamc,

I'd appreciate it if you posted a simple test that reproduces the problem, preferably to https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/neo4j

But off hand, what you said makes sense, I do not have any other tips. But if we get some code/ test to work on, we might be able to help.

Lasse

Comment: Thanks, I'll create a post on the forum. Example has been added:
https://github.com/imamchishty/neo4j-seed-spring-data